# Meaning of notation S(x) in set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, axioms

I am a beginner to set theory. axion of specification: To every set A and to every condition S(x) there corresponds a set B whose elements are exactly those element x of A for which S(x) holds. What do they mean by notation S(x)?

Comment: $S(x)$ just means that $x$ has the property $S.$ And a property is like an attribute, the only requirement being that every object either has the property or does not have the property. All the possible values $x$ are viewed as being in some set, sometimes called the universal set or just the "universe".

Comment: please answer this question 

Comment: @coffeemath should make the comment into an answer.  Then Mathews could accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Mathewslee I did answer the question, although I did not go through the axiom of separation, only your question about what $S(x)$ means.

Comment: @GEdgar I did not go through the axiom of specification, only the notation $S(x)$. Since the specification part was addressed by another comment, I didn't think I should mmake an answer.

Comment: ok thanks for the help 